# Setup oci8 on rhel 6 with REMI repository

Tags: php, apache, oracle-call-interface, rhel

I've done this before, but it was a long trial and error process that resulted with my test machine having multiple copies of php, oci8, and the instant client, and I'm still not sure what it was that I did that made it work.

So far, i've set up `yum` to use the remi repository, done `yum install php php-oci8 php-pdo`, and downloaded the oracle instant client and done `rpm -Uh oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.2.0.x86_64\ \(1\).rpm`

When I do `phpinfo()` on a page though, it still doesn't list oci8 as one of the modules.

I think the error is with the `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable, but I'm not sure what it's supposed to be set to. right now i have:

```
SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
SetEnv ORACLE_HOME /usr/lib/oracle/11.2
```

in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

The last time I got this working I think I just kept on uninstalling php and php-oci8 and re-installing until things worked.

My working server has ORACLE_HOME set like this:
[image: working server]

But the new non working one has ORACLE_HOME set here:

[image: non-working server]

how do i set the ORACLE_HOME that is in the `Enviroment` section of phpinfo()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found the answer to the issue. I installed oci8 with `PECL` instead of using `yum` and the REMI repository, but I think this should work for installing it with yum too.

Solution: turn selinux off (put it in permissive mode). This is actually oracle's suggested solution. You have to turn it off before installation to get it to install properly, and keep it off to get it to work properly.

Comment: I went through this process again, and it I could not get it to install properly through `yum` with the REMI repository, but I was able to get it working with `pecl` again.

I was having problems with an error, `no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH`. Finally found out that that means you need gcc. after I installed that and created `/etc/php.d/oci8.ini` with the line `extension=oci8.so`, I finally got it working again. 

Trial and error every time it seems with oci8!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why what's showing up in your Apache Environment is different from what's in your httpd.conf file unless you changed something, but you can set an environment variable with [putenv](https://www.php.net/putenv) so something like `putenv("ORACLE_HOME=" . $_SERVER['ORACLE_HOME']);` at the top of your code may work. Or hard-code the value if need be.

Comment: what's showing up in my Apache Environment is what's in httpd.conf. The problem (I think!) is that I need the variable to be in `Environment`, not `Apache Environment`, just like it is on my original server.

Comment: use the putenv command as I have shown. You can put this above your phpinfo() statement and view the results, you should then have ORACLE_HOME in your system environment attributes.

Comment: Ok, the putenv() put the variables there. Although, that turned out not to be the problem.